# How make my whole body slide on right when I toggle my sliding sideMenu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would make my menu slide on right when I toggle my sliding's menu. How do that ? So far I can do that only with position:fixed but it harms me because it then bothers the navigation - obviously the screen is fixed then ! So how do that without fixed my html body.

Here a demo of my situation: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zzr0jmm98

Here my Reactjs snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { menuDisplayed: false };
  toggleMenu = () => {
    console.log("toggleMenu reached");
    this.setState({
      menuDisplayed: !this.state.menuDisplayed
    });
    return;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div
          className={
            this.state.menuDisplayed ? "box_two_displayed" : "box_two_hidden"
          }
        >
          {" "}
          Box Two{" "}
        </div>
        <div
          className={
            this.state.menuDisplayed ? "box_one_displayed" : "box_one_hidden"
          }
        >
          {" "}
          Box One{" "}
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.toggleMenu} className="toggler">
          {" "}
          ToggleMenu{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here my css snippet:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.box_one_displayed {
  /* position: fixed;*/
  left: 200px;
  /* height: 100vh;*/
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.box_one_hidden {
  /* position: fixed;*/
  left: 0;
  /* height: 100vh;*/
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.box_two_displayed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.box_two_hidden {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 200px;
  left: -200px;
  background-color: cyan;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.toggler {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 350px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: just add -> position:relative; left:200px; (approx.) to your .App when your sidebar is displayed

Comment: works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need position property to do this, you should just use flex https://codepen.io/kotanbich/pen/aRYYJW .

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="navigation">
    <button id="toggle">
      ☰
    </button>
    <ul>
      <li>
        cattle
      </li>
      <li>
        poultry
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.navigation{
    width: 230px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: green;
}
.navigation.hidden{
  width: 25px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
const toggleButton =  document.getElementById('toggle');
toggleButton.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
  const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
  navigation.classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

Main container holds your sidebar and content side, main container should be set to flex. Inside main container sidebar should have flex-shrink set to 0 if you want your navigation to have the width you specified, instead of width of it's content.